# How to make fade in javascript slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I created a slider using javascript code and I want to add some motion effects in it like fade.

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var image1=new Image()
        image1.src="1.jpg"

        var image2=new Image()
        image2.src="2.jpg"

        var image3=new Image()
        image3.src="3.jpg"

        var image4=new Image()
        image4.src="4.jpg"
        //-->
    </script>

<script>
    <!--
    var step=1
    function slideit()
    {
        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
        if(step<4)
        step++
        else
        step=1
        setTimeout("slideit() ",3500)
    }
    slideit()
    //-->
    </script>
```

Is there any code for the fade or other motions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  I recommend the jQuery `animate` function.  Give it a shot.

Comment: well `jQuery` has `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are entire jquery plugins developed for just these types of things.  easySlider is one, flexSlider is another.  Bootstrap has a slider they call carousel, which while only comes with sliding effects, it's fairly easy to add cross fading.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, there are few things that must absolutely change:

- Many similar elements must be put into an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) rather than in many similar-named variables.
- Do not use `eval`, in fact, KILL IT WITH FIRE so it won't get back. `eval` is a keyword that is abused to compensate a lack of competence.

Then, for fading and motions, you may take a look at these [sliders](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/awesome-jquery-sliders/) and customize one of them with jQuery if needed. Ideally, you should not have to deal with image elements yourself as it's the slider's job.

Answer (score 0):

Give the slides container an id i.g. "images", then you can create `img` dom element and append it to the container, then change it's source every 3.5 sec and use jquery to animate the opacity(fadeIn).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var src = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'];
    var slide = 0;
    var img = new Image();
    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);

    function slideit() {
        img.style.opacity = 0;
        img.src = src[slide % 4]; //%4 will reset the counter to 0 after 3.
        img.onload = function () {
            $('#images img').animate({
                'opacity': 1
            }, 500);
            slide++;
        };
        setTimeout(slideit, 3500);
    }
    slideit();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/aJytW/)